# Bluetooth adapter is accessed using getDefalutAdaptor() call,But WifiManager is accessed using getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) why?

Tags: android, android-framework

In android,Bluetooth Adapter is accessed using `getDefaultAdapter()` call ,But WifiManager and Connectivity Manager are accessed using `getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)` and `getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)`. Why android people differentiated bluetooth accessing like that .Is there any reason for it ?

Answer (score 1):

To get a BluetoothAdapter representing the local Bluetooth adapter,

when running on JELLY_BEAN_MR1 and below, call the static `getDefaultAdapter()` method;

when running on JELLY_BEAN_MR2 and higher, retrieve it through `getSystemService(String)` with `BLUETOOTH_SERVICE`.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain it logically as I see it. 
In my understanding a [Bluetooh Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html) is an adapter while Connectivity Manager and WIFI are managers.

Talking in general terms , we call an **adapter** is like a device which connects pieces of equipment that cannot be connected directly. A **manager** is someone who controls the activities of an entity ( here WIFI and Connection respectively).  If you see the definition of [Bluetooh Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html) in the android documentation, it says:

`It lets you perform fundamental Bluetooth tasks, such as initiate device discovery, query a list of bonded (paired) devices, instantiate a BluetoothDevice using a known MAC address, and create a BluetoothServerSocket to listen for connection requests from other devices.`

So, it is acting as a bridge(adapter) between your app/UI and bluetooth to provide you with data. Now [getDefaultAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getDefaultAdapter%28%29) function is present for `Bluetooth Adapter` but not for Connectivity Manager or WIFI, as Android only supports one Bluetooth adapter for now(you can read from the link). So it makes sense to just get the default local adapter. This might be the **reason why getDefaultAdapter** present for Bluetooth adapter:

Now, if you see [Connectivity Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) class, the doc says:
`The class answers queries about the state of network connectivity. It also notifies applications when network connectivity changes.`

For [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) class, the doc says:
`The class provides the primary API for managing all aspects of Wi-Fi connectivity`

So Connectivity manager manages all the aspects of network connectivity and Wifi manager manages all aspects of Wi-Fi connectivity. They are not an adapter which are acting as a bridge as in case of Bluetooh adapter. As we are talking of two different things, **it might be the reason for difference in the implementations.**

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi Shobhit Thanks for ur answer.But For Bluetooth in getDefaultAdapter() function the code is like beow     IBinder b = ServiceManager.getService(BluetoothAdapter.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            if (b != null) {
                IBluetooth service = IBluetooth.Stub.asInterface(b);
                sAdapter = new BluetoothAdapter(service);
            }  Adater object send it to app developer like above in frameworks/base/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.java

Comment: And  For Wifi  the code is like this in ./frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java

 IBinder b = ServiceManager.getService(WIFI_SERVICE);
 IWifiManager service = IWifiManager.Stub.asInterface(b);
  WifiManager(service, ctx.mMainThread.getHandler()

For both Bluetooth and Wifi,
 Get the service and send it to their respective manegars or Blutooth adaptor.So Blutooth adaptor and Wifimanager Background mechanisam is same but exposing to app developer is different.Why ??

Comment: Interesting! I'll get back to you on this. :)

Comment: Can anybody help me on this.